# Slow wacom on virtualbox. Is it possible to solve it?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7, wacom

I have a Wacom Bamboo that works out-of-the-box on Ubuntu 11.10 (even pressure). The problem, though, comes when using it on VirtualBox.

If I don't allow VB to access it, it recognizes the tablet as a mouse and works well (the same as when you plug the tablet the first time in Windows [normally, not on VB] and don't install the drivers). However, when I install the drivers and allow VB to access the tablet via "USB devices" it becomes really slow. I get pressure-sensitivity in Photoshop, but in exchange of a lag of seconds.

The question is.. is there a chance to solve this or is this something inevitable when using a tablet through VirtualBox?

Sorry, forgot some info:

Virtualbox version is 4.1.8 (Oracle version, not the OSE), guest is Windows 7 (though I think it happened the same in XP).

Comment: Do Your Windows apps work normally or they are slow too?

Comment: It's only happening in Photoshop, though I don't know if it happens in the other apps and it's not noticeable. MAybe it's a RAM issue?

Comment: ok, did You give Your Windows more ram in VB settings?

Comment: my guess is that on VB photoshop cannot use hardware support for Wacom device.

Comment: I think I aimed at the wrong thing. More than a RAM issue (it has 2GB and shows a lot unused) it looks more as a graphics issue. Something related to the video memory, maybe. 

Can you explain what do you mean with hardware support? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the options in Virtual Box like:

```
Settings -> System -> Enable... (tablet)
```

Also ensure you have installed VB Guest Additions and the VB extension pack. And be sure to enable USB 2.0 support in USB options

[image]

Please note that Windows 7 will recognize your tablet as a touch interface and you will not see the mouse moving (although you will still be able to click). To solve this, you must disable mouse integration.

Comment: I have the same as you there (appart from the UTC thingy, though I don't think that matters).

128MB of video memory, 2D and 3D enabled in "screen"

USB enabled, with USB2.0 enabled too. I tried setting a filter (I read about it somewhere here) with no luck either. 

In system, I have the VT-x/AMD-V thing enabled, but not the other one (I don't know how to translate it from the Spanish "paginación anidada").

Comment: But did You install VB extension pack? In my case that solved the issue. Google translator says that "paginación anidada" is "nested paging". That might be useful but I don't think that is the issue here. Could You give the screen shots of Your settings? Especially memory and processor

Comment: Well, maybe it is not Ubuntu/VirtualBox/Windows issue. [Check this link please](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/237159-49-photoshop-brush-wacom-support-broke)

Comment: Weird, now it's working :S I need to disable mouse integration, though. I might have set that config when I was trying to solve the problem but not tried without mouse integration. I am going to wait to check if the problem shows up again and, if not, mark your answer as valid.

Comment: Just for the sake of it, I have 2 (out of 4) cores dedicated to the VM and almost 2GB of RAM and I do have the extension pack installed.

Comment: And thanks for the link that you put, because I could swear I tried this same config before. Maybe an Adobe update solved it.

Comment: So it is working now?

Comment: Yes, it is so far. I am going to edit your answer with a remainder to disable mouse integration.